# Doctrine 2: retrieve entities by tag, keeping all tags in the result

Tags: doctrine, many-to-many, query-builder

I have three Doctrine2 entities, interacting as follows:

1. User
2. Bookmark (one User to many Bookmarks)
3. Tag (**many** Bookmark to **many** Tags)

Bookmark entity has a ManyToMany relationship with Tag entity, as follows:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyPackage\MyBundle\Entity\Tag",cascade={"persist"},
 *      inversedBy="bookmarks")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="bookmark_tag",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="bkm_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $tags;
```

I need to retrieve all Bookmarks *tagged* with a particular tag, respecting the following rules:

1. bookmarks can be private or public: private bookmarks must be shown **only to their owner**;
2. I need to retrieve bookmarks and **all** their tags.

I'm using Doctrine QueryBuilder (the `$qb` variable in the code below). My code looks like this:

```
    $qb ->select( array('r','t') )
        ->from('Bookmark', 'r')
        ->leftJoin('r.tags', 't')
        ->where( 'r.public = 1')
        ->andWhere( 't.slug= :slug' )
        ->orWhere(
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                'r.user=:uid',
                't.slug=:slug'
            ))
        ->setParameter('uid', $userId )
        ->setParameter('slug', $tagSlug );
```

The problem with this query is, when I run `$qb->getQuery()->execute()`, the returned `Bookmark` entities have **just one tag** under `$tags`, namely the one identified by `$tagSlug` (thus, rule #2 is not met).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you only get 1 Tag in a Bookmark (and not all of them) is because your database vendor will only give you one (because of the `t.slug = :slug` part in the WHERE clause). Try the actual SQL query Doctrine generates on your database, you'll see the same result. Doctrine cannot hydrate what's not there.

A possible solution is to use a sub-query:

```
$qbOuter
    ->select(array('ob', 'ot'))
    ->from('Bookmark', 'ob')
    ->leftJoin('ob.tags', 'ot')
    ->where(
        $qbOuter->expr()->in(
            'ob.id',
            $qbInner
                ->select('ib.id')
                ->from('Bookmark', 'ib')
                ->join('ib.tags', 'it')
                ->where(
                    $qbInner->expr()->andX(
                        $qbInner->expr()->eq('it.slug', ':slug'),
                        $qbInner->expr()->orX(
                            $qbInner->expr()->eq('ib.public', ':public')
                            $qbInner->expr()->eq('ib.user', ':user')
                        )
                    )
                )
                ->getDql()
        )
    )
    ->setParameters(array(
        'slug'   => $tagSlug,
        'public' => true,
        'user'   => $userId
    ));
```

A few things to note here:

- There are 2 QueryBuilders in play: an inner one and an outer one.
- `expr()->in()` can accept a sub-query in the form of DQL, that's why there's a `getDql()` call at the end of the inner QueryBuilder.
- The aliases you use in the inner and outer queries must differ from each other. That's why I aliased Bookmark to `ib` in the inner query and `ob` in the outer one. The same goes for Tag.
- The parameters that are used in the inner QueryBuilder should be bound on the outer one. The inner QueryBuilder is only used to generate the DQL for the `IN` expression.

What will happen here is that the inner query will look up all Bookmark ids that you want, and the outer query will fetch those Bookmarks with *all* associated Tags so Doctrine can hydrate them.

PS: I've also refined your query a bit (the inner one) and made full use of the Expression library.

Comment: This worked almost out of the box, just one note: Doctrine complained about using the same aliases in the outer and inner qb's. I had to change the aliases in the inner one from 'b' to 'b1' and from 't' to 't1' and it worked. Bounty goes to you!

Comment: Thanx for the feedback, I've updated my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all tags per entry you can do it with [aggregate field](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html).
For example you have Bookmark entity with field tags

```
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="bookmark", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    private $tags;
```

and reference to bookmark

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bookmark",inversedBy="tags")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bookmark_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $bookmark;
```

And final step is creating array collection

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

This is it. Now you have access to all your tags per bookmark.

```
{% for bookmark in bookmarks %}
    <p>{{ bookmark.title }}</p>
    {% for tag in bookmark.tags %}
        <b>{{ tag.name }}</b>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did. In the returned result array, Bookmarks only had the required tag and nothing else.